# html table design not displaying correctly with 100% width, issue only in outlook

Tags: html, outlook

I have html table.I need to display the table in 100% width.

```
<table  style="width: 100%;" frame="box">
.....
</table>
```

The table is displying aligned correctly as expected in all browsers and other mail applications , but not displaying correctly in outlook with 100% width. Please help me how to resolve this issue

Comment: no need to use style. you can use width like this...
 <table  border="1" width="100%" frame="box">
    <tr>
    </tr>
    </table>

Comment: @PHP Geek.   I used in this manner also..still not working

Comment: width issue coming only in outlook